# Which one is correct: "ho dimenticato" or "mi sono dimenticato"?

Tags: word-choice, past-tense

I always thought that *dimenticare* follows the same past forming rule as other mind verbs like *pensare* (*ho pensato*), *ragionare* (*ho ragionato*), *credere* (*ho creduto*).

In Italy I encountered the form *mi sono dimenticato* and I was puzzled. Why is this form used? Why is it reflexive? Which one is the correct form and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are other similar forms:

- *mangiare*: *ho mangiato una mela* as opposed to *mi sono mangiato una mela*
- *perdere*: *che cosa ho perso?* as opposed to *che cosa mi sono perso?*

Note that *perdersi* has also a reflexive meaning, like in *mi sono perso nel bosco* (I got lost in the wood). A translation of *che mi sono perso?* would be “What did I miss?”, there's no difference in English; it would be used, for instance, by someone that arrives lately to a meeting and asks what has happened before his/her arrival. Note that *che cosa ho perso?* would sound rather strange in this context.

The form *mi sono mangiato una mela* used to be frowned upon in schools, but it's legitimate Italian and conveys a different idea about *why* I ate an apple.

- *ho mangiato una mela* just states the fact,
- *mi sono mangiato una mela* can mean that I *wanted* to eat an apple or that I was quite satisfied by eating it.

A similar difference is between *ho dimenticato* and *mi sono dimenticato*: the former is ‘objective’, while the latter is ‘subjective’. For *dimenticare/dimenticarsi* the difference is not so great as for *mangiare/mangiarsi*. In any case, the medial form (not to be confused with the reflexive, although they share the conjugation) puts greater emphasis on the subject than on the object.

Comment: Notice that _Cosa ho perso?_ can be translated as "What did I lose?" while _Cosa mi sono perso?_ could be translated with "What did I miss?" For example, if I am together my friends, I step away, and when I return I find them laughing for some reasons, I could ask _Cosa mi sono perso?_

Answer (score 5):

"Mi sono dimenticato" is not a special form of past, it's the regular past of the pronominal verb "dimenticarsi"; "dimenticare" (transitive) and "dimenticarsi" (intransitive, with "di" preposition) have usually similar meaning, but with some differences of usage.

> Accanto alla forma attiva, è frequente la coniug. pronominale dimenticarsi, che si costruisce sia transitivamente (per es.: mi son dimenticato il libro, mi son dimenticata la lezione), con sign. non dissimile dalla forma attiva (ho dimenticato il libro, ho dimenticato la lezione), sia intransitivamente con la prep. di, e in questo caso ha spesso sign. diverso: mi son dimenticato del libro (non mi sono ricordato di comperare, di portare, di mandare il libro); mi son dimenticato della lezione (m’è passato di mente che dovevo andare alla lezione, che era l’ora della lezione e sim.). Seguito da di e l’infinito può avere la coniug. attiva o pronominale senza diversità di sign.: ho dimenticato (o mi son dimenticato) di scrivergli; dimenticavo (o mi dimenticavo) di dirti un altro particolare.

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/dimenticare/

Comment: Like *ho mangiato una mela* and *mi sono mangiato una mela*; the former is more neutral, it conveys only the fact, the latter suggests that I wanted to eat an apple or that I was satisfied in eating it.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the clarification of the difference between the 2 forms. I think I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

They are both correct, and they are both used in common speaking. The main difference between these two forms is that with *ho dimenticato* you emphasize the object (what I forgot), instead *mi sono dimenticato* puts the emphasis on the subject (me).

So, for example, you will say *"Scusa mi sono dimenticato dell'appuntamento"* because you want to highlight that you forgot the meeting. In the other hand, you will say *"Ho dimenticato l'appuntamento e ora devo chiedere scusa"*, in this case you emphasize the cause, why you will have to apologize.

Event thought, they are both used, and also in my examples both forms can fit.