# Espressioni in cui non si può cambiare "mangiare" con "mangiarsi" e viceversa

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Capisco la differenza tra l'uso di "mangiare" e quello di "mangiarsi", di cui si è parlato in questa [risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1529/).

Leggendo quest'altra [risposta su Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/32159/), mi sono chiesta se quello che si sta spiegando accada anche in italiano. Cioè, in frasi in cui si usa "mangiare", è sempre possibile usare anche  "mangiarsi"?

Per esempio, consideriamo l'espressione

> mangio carne.

Possiamo anche dire

> mi mangio carne

in certi contesti  (probabilmente informali: so che il [dativo etico](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dativo-etico_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) ha una "natura intrinsecamente colloquiale")?

Sarebbe possibile dare qualche sorta di regola per sapere quando non si può usare "mangiarsi" (se veramente ci sono espressioni in cui non si può utilizzare)?

Possiamo arrivare alla conclusione, come nella risposta che ho menzionato, che quando l'oggetto di "mangiare" è *unbounded* (si veda la definizione più sotto), allora non si può usare "mangiarsi" (magari con qualche eccezione)? Ci sono altri casi in cui l'utilizzo di "mangiarsi" non è possibile?

Cito da quella risposta:

> An object is bounded (in this sense) if it's definite (*la manzana*, *esta manzana*) or appears as a definite quantity (*una manzana*, *dos manzanas*) or expresses totality (*toda la manzana*, *todas las manzanas*). For all of those you can use *comerse*, although *comer* is correct too, with the differences in connotation that you already know.

Traduzione in italiano delle espressioni in castigliano:

- *manzana* = mela
- *manzanas* = mele
- *la manzana* = la mela
- *esta manzana* = questa mela
- *una manzana* = una mela
- *dos manzanas* = due mele
- *toda la manzana* = tutta la mela
- *todas las manzanas* = tutte le mele
- *comerse* = mangiarsi
- *comer* = mangiare

> You cannot use *comerse* when the object is unbounded, i.e. when it's countable but not definitely quantified (*manzanas*) or when it's uncountable (*manzana*, as in apple used as an ingredient of something, whether explicit or not). Here you must use *comer*.

Sulla risposta di Spanish.SE, si è anche arrivati alla conclusione che in castigliano esistono espressioni costrutte con "mangiarsi" (beh, con la traduzione di "mangiarsi" infatti: "comerse") nelle quali non si può usare "mangiare" (in realtà, "comer"), cioè, in cui l'uso di "mangiarsi" è d'obbligo.

Cito dalla risposta menzionata:

> There are some cases, not obviously derived from the rules above, where *comerse* is to be used and *comer* would be wrong. These are [...]:
>
> - Fixed phrases: “*Me comí todo*” (which literally means "I ate everything", but can figuratively mean "I ate a lot, too much, until I couldn't eat no more"); also “*Me comí la vida*”.
> - Figurative expressions: “*comerse las eses*” ("to eat up one's S's", i.e. s-aspiration); “*comerse a alguien*” ("to have sex with someone"); "*comerse una paliza* / *un reto*" ("to put up with a -- usu. undeserved or excessive -- beating or reprimand").
> - Consumption of prey by carnivores: “*El león se comió a la gacela*” ("The lion ate the gazelle", even if the lion didn't actually ate the whole gazelle).

La traduzione letterale di "Me comí la vida" sarebbe "Mi sono mangiato (o mi mangiai) la vita". Debbo dire che alcune delle espressioni di senso figurato sopra menzionate sono sconosciute per me: la lingua spagnola ha molte varianti regionali. Ne potrei aggiungere altre che non appaiono qui e che sì conosco, ma non credo sia veramente utile.

Esistono anche espressioni tali in italiano, cioè, espressioni costrutte con "mangiarsi" nelle quali non si può usare "mangiare", ma in cui l'uso di "mangiarsi" è d'obbligo? ("obbligo" nel senso di modo naturale di esprimersi per un italofono, non di regola grammaticale che vieti l'uso di "mangiare" senza "si")<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1. Faccio un esempio perché si capisca meglio a cosa mi riferisco. Non esiste nessuna regola grammaticale che vieti dire "soffio il mio naso" o "soffia il proprio naso". Tuttavia, dubito che nessun italofono usasse queste frasi in modo naturale per esprimere questa idea (sì, è sempre possibile immaginare qualche contesto peculiare in cui si possa forzare il linguaggio). Si direbbe invece "mi soffio il naso" o "si soffia il naso". In questo senso possiamo dire che è "obbligatorio" usare "soffiarsi" in queste espressioni.</sup>

---

**Aggiornamento:**

Sulla risposta di Spanish.SE hanno dimenticato di tenere in considerazione espressioni analoghe a, per esempio, questa:

> Mio figlio non mi mangia verdura.

Comment: A me piace molto "until I couldn't eat no more"...

Comment: ...e comunque, credo che in Italiano il discorso menzionato (bounded, countable ecc.) non si applichi proprio.

Comment: Se è veramente così, secondo me, questo rende la domanda ancora più interessante.

Comment: Ti segnalo che questi dativi/accusativi sono a volte un rafforzativo ("deciditi!"), a volte un "dativo etico" come dice @Nico, a volte frasi idiomatiche ("farsi qualcuno" invece di mangiarselo come in Spagnolo - però da noi si "mangia con gl'occhi", oppure "farsi" e basta - cioé drogarsi). Alla fine, c'è un po' di tutto, e credo che in fondo le cose si sovrappongano.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Infatti molto spesso qui "non me la bevo" ;-)

Comment: *Unbounded* potrebbe tradursi con illimitato (quasi letterale), oppure impreciso/imprecisato, indefinito o "non definito", indeterminato, non quantificato. Dipende dal contesto: in questo caso *illimitato* potrebbe andare bene ma, se non è un termine specialistico già affermato nell'uso, può essere percepito come indicazione di "grande quantità", che è tutt'altro.

Comment: "Esistono anche espressioni ... mangiarsi è obbligatorio"? NO: non ci sono regole grammaticali al riguardo; ci possono essere frasi fatte, probabilmente regionali o dialettali, per esempio "mangiarsi perfino la strada per andare a casa" (mangiare smodatamente) ma, per l'appunto, sono idiomatiche.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107943/discussion-on-question-by-charo-espressioni-in-cui-non-si-puo-cambiare-mangiare).

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  «Esistono anche espressioni ...  in cui l'uso di "mangiarsi" è d'obbligo?» Hai detto che la risposta a questa domanda è "no", ma non credo sia così (a meno che, nell'unica risposta che c'è adesso, neanche il punto 3) risponda alla domanda). Non sto chiedendo nessuna regola grammaticale.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Come spiega in dettaglio l'[Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dativo-etico_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/), che fa esempi come *soffiarsi il naso*, *rompersi la testa*, *tingersi i capelli*, ecc., uno dei casi in cui è obbligatorio usare *mangiarsi* (quindi, parte della risposta all'ultima domanda, che insisto, non credo sia "no") è l'espressione *mangiarsi le unghie*: non si può dire "*sempre mangio le mie unghie", si deve dire "sempre mi mangio le unghie". Questo è interessante perché è diverso da altre lingue.

Comment: @Charo: A volte il riflessivo è finto, una scorciatoia per indicare (debolmente) il possesso: "Mangiarsi le unghie"="Mangiare le proprie unghie"; "Mangiarsi la preda"="Mangiare la propria preda". Si può dire "mangiarsi la preda altrui", ma non "tingersi i
capelli altrui", e dire "tingere i capelli", senza specificare altro, è corretto e significa tingere i propri. Ripeto, la particella
"si" non è obbligatoria.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Allora è che la Treccani è sbagliata. Non sapevo che in italiano una frase come "sempre mangia le proprie unghie" fosse un modo tanto naturale di esprimersi.

Comment: @Charo, confermo che “mangiarsi le unghie” è pressoché l'unico modo per esprimere quel concetto. Ogni altra formulazione si potrebbe usare solo in contesti piuttosto forzati. “Gino... [rumore] ...mangia le unghie.” “Come? Gino mangia le unghie a qualcuno??” “No, mangia le proprie unghie!” (e anche lì, pur volendo rafforzare, forse direi più “si mangia le sue, di unghie”).

Comment: @DaG: "Altre lingue" nel commento precedente sono, per esempio, francese, inglese e tedesco, ma non castigliano, né catalano, che hanno lo stesso fenomeno ("comerse las uñas" o "morderse las uñas" / "menjar-se les ungles" o "mossegar-se les ungles").

Comment: @dag Stai dicendo che in questa pagina https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onicofagia (ma pure altre più colloquiali) ci sono errori d'Italiano? "Mangiare le proprie unghie" può non essere comune, ma è senz'altro preciso, corretto, e più adatto a un contesto formale come un'enciclopedia o un trattato medico.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Se avessi un dollaro per ogni errore di italiano nella it.Wikipedia, Jeff Bezos mi farebbe le pulizie a casa. Ciò detto, a me personalmente “mangiare le proprie unghie” suona di calco dall'inglese (come quel “la ciurma alzò i loro cappelli” irriso da Bianciardi). Poi, libero ognuno di esprimersi come meglio crede.

Answer (score -2):

1) "Possiamo anche dire questo? Mi mangio carne". 
No. In italiano "mangio carne" e "mangio la carne" per designare abitudini sono equipollenti. Non si tratta di "boundedness", ma di "definiteness". Il post spagnolo che citi confonde le due nozioni. In inglese si può solo usare l'articolo per specificare il referente ("definiteness") "I eat the meat that you cook and not the meat that others cook" vs. "I usually eat meat". Questa differenziazione non si applica all'italiano. Se però si parla di un episodio singolo e non abituale, l'italiano richiede l'articolo o un partitivo "adesso mangio (del)la carne".

2) Il punto precedente è strettamente legato alla risposta che citi all'inizio. Il cosiddetto "dativo etico" (termine usato diversamente in diverse lingue) riguarda l'uso colloquiale del "si" con certi verbi: "mi bevo una birra", "mi fumo una sigaretta", dove il pronome riflessivo indica un "beneficiary", vale a dire si riferisce al fatto che l'enunciatore fa un favore a se stesso concedendosi qualcosa che gli fa piacere. Alcune informazioni le trovi nell'articolo di Niclot in https://benjamins.com/catalog/tsl.106 (anche se il tema che tratta è più vasto). Questo "favore" è sempre legato a un episodio unico, vale a dire non è compatibile con l'uso di "carne" senza articolo, che indica abitualità: *"mi mangio sempre carne".

3) Ci sono usi obbligatori e non colloquiali come in 2) del riflessivo in contesti figurati: "si è mangiato l'eredità/un patrimonio", "si è rimangiato la parola".

Comment: La domanda non è sull'uso di "mangio carne" versus "mangio la carne": il punto 1) e il punto 2) veramente non corrispondono a quello che si sta chiedendo (eccetto l'ultima frase che, però, non mi sembra del tutto motivata da quello che si spiega prima).   Il punto 3) risponde alla domanda, ma il contenuto è un po' povero. Per migliorare la risposta, suggerirei di cercare di elaborare su quello che si sta chiedendo.

Comment: Non troverei nulla di strano in *Ora mi mangio carne e vediamo se il medico ha qualcosa da dire!* che secondo la risposta non sarebbe possibile.

Comment: Secondo me è più che altro una questione d'uso: "mi mangio carne" non è scorretto, solo meno frequente per i motivi che spieghi al punto 2. L'articolo di Treccani sul dativo etico (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/dativo-etico_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) dà molti spunti interessanti in tal senso e tra gli esempi cita proprio un caso simile con mangiare (" Maria dice che il piccolo le mangia poca verdura"). @Charo potrebbe rispondere anche alla seconda parte della tua domanda sulle espressioni figurate (o forse ti riferivi solo all'uso con "mangiare?)

Comment: @OldManofAran Infatti anche l'articolo che cito nella mia risposta sopra si occupa in dettaglio di questo tema.

Comment: @egreg "ora mangio carne" nel senso che citi non si riferisce al momento in cui stai per mangiare la carne, ma a un'intenzione generale o futura. In ogni caso, per restare in topic, non credo diresti "ora mi mangio carne".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107917/discussion-between-nico-and-charo).

Comment: @Nico "In passato ero vegetariano ma ora mi mangio carne senza problemi"

Comment: Nell'esempio "mio figlio non mi mangia verdura" il narratore sta indicando un'abitudine del figlio: non mi sembra che l'uso del dativo etico sia obbligatoriamente "legato a un episodio unico" e incompatibile con l'espressione di abitualità, come si afferma al punto 2). Potrei anche dire  "tutti i fine settimana mi mangiavo una pizza".